# How to populate a form with current user data with Django UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a User defined, partly, as so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

...
```

A user can either be a Freelancer or a Client. Take Freelancer as an example:

```
class Freelancer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
```

I've created a form for a user to register. When I register I get the type of user they selected and create a record in the appropriate table:

```
if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            # create subgroup based on user type
            if user.type == 1:
                fl = Freelancer(user=user)
                fl.save()
```

So now I have a User and a Freelancer linked to that user and now I wish to let the user be able to edit all their details:

```
class Profile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    second_form_class = FreelanceUpdateForm
    template_name = "freelancestudent/profile.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Profile, self).get_queryset()
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return queryset.none()
        else:
            return queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(Profile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET, instance=self.request.user)
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET, instance=self.request.user)
            return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form = self.form_class
        form2 = self.second_form_class
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(
            object=self.object, form=form, form2=form2))
```

The forms look like this:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class FreelanceUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Freelancer
        fields = ('university',)
```

The problem is it won't populate the data with existing data. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122096/django-class-based-views-updateview-with-two-model-forms-one-submit) which led me to the `instance=self.request.user` idea and as I debug I can see it does get that instance of a user but no population. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `initial` attribute to populate your form.

Here is an example to populate email field of the user. Don't forget to remove `self.request.GET`, it's useless in this view and it can't work with:

```python
context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.request.user, initial={'email':self.request.user.email})
```

Read Django documentation for more information: [dynamic-initial-values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

Comment: I still get the same result, when submitting the form.